disk full at 100%
I have an ubuntu 20.04.02 running with an osticket server since 2021. Everything always worked fine until this morning when i had "http error 500" accessing the server via IP/browser.
I installed putty and I can access the server through command line and I think I have the ssd full, but it's impossible that it's full because of mysql database, so there must be some other stuff occupying the space (its a 500gb ssd, the database should be around 50gb).
How can I see/check what's taking up the space and safely get some free space without destroying anything?

remove /var/cache/apt/archive/*.deb Possibly root has a very large mailbox with all errors. And check /var/log (and underdirectories): they may be some very large and old log you do not need

I like ncdu over using du commands on each folder. You can install ncdu, if you do not have it. From / run  sudo ncdu  But issues often are some error that then causes log files to fill up. You may want to check logs in /var/log.

This question is similar to: Tracking down where disk space has gone on Linux?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

if you are still able to log in, then here is what you can do to reclaim some 1% or better disk space before the system becomes totally non-functional:

before doing any of the rm commands I suggest, you can do a du -sh <folder> to see the size of it to have an understanding
you have snap installed and that /snap link typically points to /var/lib/snapd.

you can immediately do rm -r /var/lib/snapd/cache/*


I am a redhat user which uses yum, or dnf.  As such there is /var/lib/cache/dnf/.

you can immediately do rm -r /var/lib/cache/dnf/*;  Adjust syntax for ubuntu.


you can do a du -sh /var/lib/cache/* to see what an offending folder is as well, and possibly just remove everything under /var/lib/cache
per your df -h output the /home is not on a separate partition, so do a du -sh /home/* to see if there is an offending user folder and then delete accordingly as you look into it.
a du -sh /var/log/* is often where some log file may have run out of control filling up your disk.
using ncdu which is an ncurses text based du with a top-like display in an ssh terminal can be a very useful way of finding offending folders that are filling  up the disk.  Do a cd / then do ncdu and navigate as necessary.
the /tmp folder nowadays is often a tmpfs mount, but even if not it is generally safe to do a rm -r /tmp/*.


you also asked : Do you think its safe to unplug this ssd from the server and plug it to another computer with ubuntu and graphic interface? so it can be easier to delete files? or i might screw up the boot?

yes that is often a good method.  yes it is possible to screw things up, but only if you are reckless and really have no idea what you are doing... don't touch the /boot folder or anything under /etc for starters.  You do not need another ubuntu system; any other linux operating system will work  to mount the disk's root partition; per your df output do not mount /dev/sda1 nor /dev/sda2.  Any other linux OS that supports mounting the file system that was used for your / partition.

Hi Ron! thank you so much for your answer. i tried the rm -r /var/lib/snapd/cache/*
but im getting a "Permission Denied" altough i am pretty sure i logged in with admin rights. Any idea why i am getting this?

If you log in as a regular user then you are relying on sudo and that configuration for whether or not your account specifically has sudo rights and permissions to perform various operations.  the snap folder is typically owned by root.root so you would want to su and be root to do most of the rm commands and not be inconvenienced.

And then if becoming root on that system is a problem, for whatever reason, then that's where you'll want to power off that system and mount that disk on another linux system where you do have unfettered root access to be able to delete anything.... provided there is not disk encryption involved.

Ron you're being a great help. Indeed im having problems with 'su'. For example, i do a 'sudo df -h' it asks me for the password, i insert password and it works fine. however if i try to do "su" after asking the password says "authentication failure". Inside the /var/log$ is there any command that i can use to delete all the files and folders inside this without su? millions thanks man

Ok so this is where i am at the moment. I plugged the ssd by an USB interface to a laptop with ubuntu. one partition popped up (around 2.7gb) with "efi" and "grub" on the inside, no other partitions appeared. i did a 'sudo fdisk -l' and i see a /dev/sda3/ with 444.1Gb which i guess its tha partition i am looking for. so i did 'sudo mount /dev/sda3/  /mnt' and i am getting this: "mount: /mnt unkown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'. dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.
Any hint on what should i do next? thanks!

update:
i installed lvm2 using "$ sudo apt-get install lvm2" and after that i can see the partition on ubuntu but i cant delete files. only see/read
hints? thanks!

i figured you would run into problems trying to mount your logical volume, which is why I did not elaborate.  It is a matter of first having LVM installed to support that, then you have to import that VG...  if I find online instructions I'll post it.

for starters: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/4/html/cluster_logical_volume_manager/vg_move

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/612814/lvm-export-and-import-how-to-move-a-vg-to-another-machine-with-a-equally-named

Hi Ron! Good morning, how are you? One question, if i import the VG on a new machine just to be able to clear disk space, will i be able to use that same ssd afterwards on the original machine? will it still work/boot? thanks

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/4123

when you mark the VG inactive and export it on the original system, then it won't be accessible on that system until you import it again just like you are doing now on this new system.

after you import your VG on this new system and then delete whatever you need to off the / partition to reclaim space then you will want to do an unmount followed by vgchange -an <name> and vgexport <name> on it before putting it back to the original system.  Then when back on the original system you will have to pvscan, vgimport <name>  and vgchange -ay <name> to it before being able to mount it.

thank you so much for your help Ron. for safety reasons at the moment i am cloning the original ssd with TODO BACKUP (ease us) just to be safe and dont screw anything up. The Clone ssd is 1tb (original one is 500gb) another option would be to make the partition size bigger on the cloned ssd. more details soon, still 8 hours left on the clone process :\
